# how to check a list ID exist in context and how to update it in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity

i have a question.
we have a list of ID. i want to search all list ID are exist in myContext.Student
and then update the status field of Student entity.
please help me how do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var matches = myContext.Student.Where(s => list.Contains(s.id));
foreach(var student in matches)
  student.status = newStatus;
myContext.SaveChanges();
```